# Second Managed Metadata Service not accessible from Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint-server, mms

I have created a second managed metadata service for a Content Type Hub.

If I click on my newly created managed metadata service from Central Administration/Manage service applications , I see the

> Term Store Management Tool for my first Managed Metadata Service.

Are you familiar with this situation and do you know what's wrong?

My new MMS is connected with my Content Hub web application. I see that I can manage the terms from the content hub site collection, so maybe it's not a big problem. Still I would like to know if that behaviour is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the 2nd MMS service, you have to connect new MMS proxy to central admin Web applications.

1. `Go to Central admin > Application Management > Manage web Application > Over here`
2. `Click on the Central Admin > from Ribbon Click on Service
   connection >` on this dialog, Make Sure 2nd Instance of MMS selected
   / connected here.
3. After connecting, please test again